# Rails will not let me destroy scaffolding from nifty generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, generator, scaffolding

I was following one of the railscasts tutorials and decided to install nifty generators. Well, being a rails noob I didn't realize that the way parameters are handled changed. Now I can't undo any of my changes. So far I managed to roll back the database but every time I try to run

```
rails destroy nifty:scaffold mymodel
```

I get the error message

> `attr_accessible` is extracted out of rails into a gem. Please use new recommended protection model for params(strong_parameters) or add `protected_attributes` to your Gemfile to use old one.

So I did. I added

```
gem 'protected_attributes'
```

and ran

```
bundle install
```

Then I tried to destroy it and it errored out again. I really hope nifty didn't just screw up my project. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, this not a real solution, but a possible workaround: if the output of the `rails generate nifty:scaffold mymodel` command is still in your terminal buffer, you could manually delete the files it created.

And if the output isn't available, you could do `rails generate nifty:scaffold mymodel2` in order to see what files nifty:scaffold created before manually deleting the corresponding files for `mymodel`.

Not elegant, but it might get you over the hump.

Comment: Yes this was an option I considered but I dont want to do that because it modified the routes and who knows what else.

Comment: Ah, grasshopper.  git is your friend.  learn to love it and it will help you in cases like this!